# Data isn't displaying from another table in CGridView Widget

Tags: php, yii, widget

I have two table `Event` and `EventCategory`. I am using `zii.widgets.grid.CGridView` widget to display all the events in the admin section.

I have created the following relations between tables.

**Relation in EventCategory model:**

> 'event' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Event', 'category_id'),

**Relation in Event model:**

> 'category' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'EventCategory', 'category_id'),

The following code I am using to display the Events:

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'event-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
    'filter'=>$model,
    'summaryText'=> '',
    'columns'=>array(
         array('header'=>'Id','name'=>'event_id','filter'=>''),
         'event_code',
         'category.evntcatm_name',
         'event_name',
         array(
             'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
             'htmlOptions'=>array('class'=>'actions aligncenter'),
             'deleteButtonImageUrl'=>false,
             'updateButtonImageUrl'=>false,
             'viewButtonImageUrl'=>false
          ),
    ),
)); ?>
```

`'category.evntcatm_name'` doesn't display anything. It is just creating the blank column with **NO ERROR**. What I am missing here.

Comment: Can you double check if the column is actually filled in the db

Comment: Yes. Data is there, but its not displaying anything.

Comment: Do you have your relation set up in your model?

Comment: Yes. I have done that. I have added the `relations` in the question description. Let me know, if you find any mistake there.

Comment: Based on your comments on others, I can say that your 'category' is not filled for some reason. Get an event that has a category and try to do a var_dump($model->category). It shouldn't return null if the $model has a category assigned

Comment: Also double check your foreign keys. I believe relations in Yii don't work without foreign keys.

Comment: Perfect. The foreign key wasn't set properly. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use code like this:

```
'columns' = array(
    /*YOUR DATA*/
    array(      
        'name' => 'category_id', 
        'value' => function($data) {
           return !empty($data->category) ? $data->category->evntcatm_name : null;
    }),
)
```

This way can solve your problem with "Trying to get property of non-object". If you see blank cell in grid that means you miss relation (or it doesnt exist, in this way you should check relation condition or database)

Comment: I've got no error, but also the column is blank. Suggest something please.

Comment: @Mohit Bhansali can you show your db schema? May be you mistook relation rules?

Comment: Relations was fine, I didn't set foreign key properly. Its done now. I got the proper results.

Answer (score 3):

Please try something like it

```
$data->category->evntcatm_name
```

Comment: Then you have something wrong with your query because this is the correct answer. And stop downvoting people who are trying to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a few wild guesses:

- Is category.evntcatm_name correctly spelled?
- Is there actually data in the evntcatm_name field to begin with?

I know it might sound too simple to miss, but the error almost has to be on that level.
Try finding a category using the primary key and output it's evntcatm_name.

```
$cat = EventCategory::model()->findByPk(1);
echo $cat->evntcatm_name;
```

Maybe if you could share your schema for those two tables?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
    array(
              'header' => 'Category Title',
              'value' => '$data->category->evntcatm_name'
    ),
```

instead of 'category.evntcatm_name'

Comment: I am getting this error. `Trying To Get Property Of Non-Object Error.`

Answer (score -1):

The model instance is not object now in the Cgidview:
Try

```
$data['category']['evntcatm_name'];
```